# Cannot read property of undefined in react navigation native with typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm building a react native app and I'm having trouble passing props to another screen using react-navigation/native.

Navigation set up

```
export type RootStackParamList = {
  Home: HomeProps,
  LoginDemo: undefined,
  Login: undefined
};

const Stack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();
const store = configureStore();

export const Navigation: React.FC = () => {

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="LoginDemo" component={LoginDemo} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home}/>
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

Code that does the screen switching

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    if (patrolUnits.completed) {
      if (patrolUnits.error !== null)
        showAlert("error", patrolUnits.error.toString());
      else
        navigation.replace('Home', {patrolUnitId: patrolUnits.data[0].id});
    }

  }, [patrolUnits.completed]);
```

The screen that I am switching to

```
export const Home: React.FC<RouteProp<RootStackParamList, "Home">> = routeProps => {

    const props = routeProps.params;

    const { patrolUnitId } = props;

    return (<View>
        <Text>{patrolUnitId.toString()}</Text>
    </View>)
};
```

And the props that should be passed

```
export type HomeProps = {

    patrolUnitId: number;

}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong. I've been trying to figure this out for hours. I've tried googling but almost everything that's recommended for me is for regular react, not react native.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.  The issue is with this declaration:

```
React.FC<RouteProp<RootStackParamList, "Home">>
```

The `RouteProp` type defines the type for the prop which is passed as `route`.  Here you are declaring that the `RouteProp` is the entire props for the component instead of a single prop called `route`.

You want:

```
const Home: React.FC<{route: RouteProp<RootStackParamList, "Home">}> = ({route}) => {
```

The render components for each `Stack.Screen` will be called with props `navigation` (type `StackNavigationProp`) and `route` (type `RouteProp`).  There is also a type `StackScreenProps` which defines an object with both props.  So you can also do this:

```
const Home: React.FC<StackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, "Home">> = ({route}) => {
```

On the component with the `useEffect` hook, you need to make sure that `navigation` is included in the props and is typed correctly.

You can use:

```
type MyComponentProps = {
    navigation: StackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList, "Name">
}
```

or

```
type MyComponentProps = StackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, "Name">
```

[Expo Demo](https://snack.expo.io/@lindapaiste/react-navigation-with-typescript)